# Why my strategy exits at the same time it enters

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am using a pull-back strategy for entry with a recent swing low for stop loss (indicated by the green line in the picture) and a 1:1 risk/reward ratio. However, in backtesting, it appears that my code exits a trade the moment it enters. I can't seem to figure out why it is doing that.

[image]

Here is my code for entry/exit logic:

```
//long condition
// we go long when there is a buy signal and no opentrades.

longCondition = buy_signal and strategy.opentrades == 0

// entry
if longCondition
    //Stop loss will be a recent swing low
    longSL = stopLevel

    //we will target for 1:1 risk/reward from stop loss
    longTP = close + (close - longSL)

    strategy.entry("LONG", strategy.long, comment = "LONG")
    strategy.exit("EXIT LONG", "LONG", stop = longSL, limit = longTP, comment = "LONG SL/TP")
```

Although it doesn't do that for all trades, but still majority of them. here is a successful example.

[image]

Here is the code to calculate swing High/Low and Simple Pull-Back:

```
//====LOGIC FOR SWING HIGH/LOW====
strategy("SIMPLE PULL BACK + SWING HIGH/LOW", overlay=true, precision = 4, initial_capital=1000, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100, currency=currency.USD, process_orders_on_close=true, pyramiding=0)

// Inputs
pvtLenL       = input.int(3, minval=1, title="Pivot Length Left Hand Side")
pvtLenR       = input.int(3, minval=1, title="Pivot Length Right Hand Side")
showStop      = input.bool(true, title="Show Recent Low Stop?")

// Get High and Low Pivot Points
pvthi_ = ta.pivothigh(high, pvtLenL, pvtLenR)
pvtlo_ = ta.pivotlow(low, pvtLenL, pvtLenR)

// Force Pivot completion before plotting.
Shunt = 1 //Wait for close before printing pivot? 1 for true 0 for flase
maxLvlLen = 0 //Maximum Extension Length
pvthi = pvthi_[Shunt]
pvtlo = pvtlo_[Shunt]

// Count How many candles for current Pivot Level, If new reset.
counthi = ta.barssince(not na(pvthi))
countlo = ta.barssince(not na(pvtlo))
 
pvthis = fixnan(pvthi)
pvtlos = fixnan(pvtlo)
hipc = ta.change(pvthis) != 0 ? na : color.fuchsia
lopc = ta.change(pvtlos) != 0 ? na : color.rgb(0, 207, 7)   

// Stop Levels
stopLevel = ta.valuewhen(pvtlo_, low[pvtLenR], 0)

// ====LOGIC FOR PULL-BACK====
lookback = input(defval = 5, title = 'Lookback')

lower_barrier = input(defval = 20, title = 'Lower Barrier')
lower_threshold = input(defval = 33, title = 'Lower Threshold')

upper_barrier = input(defval = 80, title = 'Upper Barrier')
upper_threshold = input(defval = 67, title = 'Upper Threshold')

rsi = ta.rsi(close, lookback)

buy_signal  = rsi >= lower_barrier and rsi < rsi[1] and rsi[1] > lower_barrier and rsi[1] < lower_threshold and rsi[2] < lower_barrier
alertcondition(buy_signal, title = "LONG")

sell_signal = rsi <= upper_barrier and rsi > rsi[1] and rsi[1] < upper_barrier and rsi[1] > upper_threshold and rsi[2] > upper_barrier
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the way you design your longSL that make you exit the trade as soon as your enter it.
Your longSL is certainly lower than the close value.
But without the complete code, it is hard to help you more.

Comment: I have included the logic that calculates swing high/low. I borrowed that code from "Swing High/Low" by millerrh in Indicators.